# Connect existing Eclipse project to existing Git repository

Tags: eclipse, git, pydev

I have an Eclipse workspace in `~/EclipseWorkspaces/Sabia` with a number of projects under Ubuntu 15.10. The source code for these projects resides in a Git repository at `~/GitRepositories/Sabia`.

I can find no way to tell Eclipse in the Pydev Package Explorer that the projects use the Git Repository. If I try to use *Team->Share*, the system rejects the Git repository because a directory for each project exists in the repository and Eclipse is trying to move the project to the repository which already has a project directory.

I tried [the suggestion by Michal Grzejszczak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425286/connect-existing-eclipse-project-to-existing-git-repository/35427762#35427762) but unfortunately it does not work because the Git Repository does not contain complete projects, only the source trees for the projects. The Eclipse metadata is in `/EclipseWorkspaces`, not in the Git Repository so `import projects` on the Git Repository perspective does not work.

In addition when I tried to delete the projects I got the following error message:

> AppFrame (*One of my projects*) contains resources that are not in sync with `/home/jonathan/Dropbox/EclipseWorkspaces/Sabia/AppFrame`. Press 'Continue' to force delete`

for half of my projects.

Unfortunately the message gives no more information and I have no idea what kind of problem might actually exist. I am not prepared to delete any flawed projects until I have corrected whatever was wrong.

How can I tell the Eclipse Pydev Package Explorer where the Git repository resides?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you thus have the source code of your projects in 2 locations: your eclipse workspace and your `GitRepositories` folder. Right? Outside the eclipse metadata, is there any difference between those project folders?

Comment: The Eclipse workspace contains the Eclipse metadata only, the Git Repository contains the program content. The two are disjoint.

Answer (score 7):

You need to first add this repository to `Git repositories` view in Eclipse. Then remove these project from workspace, but without deleting contents and then the most crucial part import them back with "Import projects..." from context menu after right clicking `Working tree` of the repo in `Git repositories` view.

[image]

That should make your projects managed by Git.

Comment: Please see my expanded problem description for the results of trying your suggestion.